# Yii CDBCommand getText to show all variables in the SQL

Tags: php, yii

I am using Yii's Yii::app()->db->createCommand() to build an SQL query.  In order to view the SQL code that Yii generates, I am using the getText() method of CDBCommand.  Problem is, when I use the getText() method on SQL code that contain parameters, for example:

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
           ->select("name")
           ->from('package')
           ->where('id=:id', array(':id'=>5))
           ->queryRow();
```

the getText() method returns the following SQL:

```
select name from package where id=:id
```

instead of:

```
select name from package where id=5
```

This is fine for simple queries, but for more complex queries with lots of parameters, it is quite a pain to copy/paste each parameter into the SQL code to test it.

Is there any way to display the parameters directly inside the SQL using getText() or some other method in Yii?

Cheers!

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Looks like you're after the PDOStatement that Yii is preparing:

```
$cmd = Yii::app()->createCommand();

$cmd->select("name")
       ->from('package')
       ->where('id=:id', array(':id'=>5))
       ->queryRow();

// returns a PDO Statement - http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php
Yii::log($cmd->getPdoStatement()->queryString);
```

Does that work for you?  Seems like it should (code untested).

Comment: Nope, this returned the same statement, like 
"select name from package where id=:id", see this article for real workaround http://daveyshafik.com/archives/605-debugging-pdo-prepared-statements.html . It's not about PDO in Yii, but it can be applied for yii too

Answer (score 3):

```
$sql = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
  ->select("name")
  ->from('package')
  ->where('id=:id', array(':id'=>5))
  ->queryRow();

$query=str_replace(
   array_keys($sql->params),
   array_values($sql->params),
   $sql->getText()
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the CDbConnetion::enableParamLogging propery. For instance, in config/main.php:

```
'db' => array (
        'enableParamLogging' => true,
```

and the shown and logged error will contain the bound values.

Answer (score 0):

why don you try as below.i am not an expert just posting to my knowledge if its no suitable for your prob pardon me...

```
               $connection=Yii::app()->db;
            $id=5; // you can able to change by "GET" or "POST" methods
    $sql="SELECT name FROM package WHERE id = :id ";
    $command = $connection->createCommand($sql);
    $command->bindParam(":id",$id,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $dataReader=$command->query();          
    $rows=$dataReader->readAll();
    $namevalue=array();
    foreach($rows as $max)
    {
    $namevalue = $max['name'];
    }   
    echo $namevalue; // which is the value u need
```

thank you...