# Yii CDbCommand: getText() with parameters not possible?

Tags: yii

By executing the following command:

```
echo Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('*')
    ->from('User')
    ->where('user_id=:uid', array(':uid'=>123))
    ->getText();
```

we get

> SELECT * FROM `User` WHERE user_id=:uid

when we should be getting

> SELECT * FROM `User` WHERE user_id=123

Binding does not work when using *getText()*. Why? Is it a bug?

Comment: It's not bug, it's a feature

Comment: possible duplicate of [Yii CDBCommand getText to show all variables in the SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226625/yii-cdbcommand-gettext-to-show-all-variables-in-the-sql)

Comment: @Dinistro that question is similar and does not have any correct answers.